# having trouble using ajax to display the data with PHP and POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run a php script that pulls data from a DB with the click of a button. I want to use ajax so the page doesn't refresh. I've tested using normal post / submit with page refresh and it works but I am having trouble using ajax to display the data. This is my code:

```
  <form method="get" id="ghosts">
         <div id=rightc>
              <h7>Select Hosts:</h7>
     <br></br>

      <select id="group" name="group" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
           <?php
        $link=mysql_connect($mysqlserver, $username, $password) or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());
        $gquery=" SELECT groupname FROM groups";
        $gresult=mysql_query($gquery) or die ("Query to get data from firsttable failed: ".mysql_error());
        while ($grow=mysql_fetch_array($gresult)) {
        $groupname=$grow["groupname"];
            echo "<option>$groupname</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
     <input type="hidden" name="ghosts" value="1" />
     <noscript> <input type="submit" name="ghosts" id="group" value="Choose Group" /></noscript>

  </form>
```

Comment: Where are the input fields of the form?

Comment: Use GET method and getting value using POST `isset($_POST['ahosts'])`

Comment: Big clue. **`$(".result")` matches nothing.**

Comment: You should edit your question with you form code and (if possible), your 'search.php' code.

Comment: @Peter the form code is in there and the PHP is not neccessary, though confirmation that it returns data would be good.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @Popnoodles you're right about the form code, but I think that the PHP code may help because we could see the way he is getting the form data

Comment: To use AJAX effectively you should put your PHP with its requests to MySQL in a separate file. You would then make the AJAX request to the PHP file [and return the data](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for all looking, the code is all self contained so this is search.php. The form is simple its just a button to trigger the script. It is show above in the code. Maybe there is a better way of doing this ? really what i want is a button that says search then runs the php code to pull data from the db using ajax

Comment: That's the same file that it's pulling in? So `<head>` and `<body>` and `<script>` are all returned in the ajax calls. ... You need to separate the files such that the one you're calling returns only the contents you want to add to the page.

Answer (score 4):

If your search.php file returned HTML, and assuming that the ajax works (it looks like it should), you're trying to put the contents into an element that doesn't exist.

```
$(".result").html(data);
```

It needs to exist on the page. Add this somewhere.

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

However, your PHP doesn't return any data because of this condition `if(isset($_POST['ahosts']))` which requests a parameter that isn't in the form and uses the wrong request method.

You're using GET (`$.get()`), so in the PHP it needs to read

```
if(isset($_GET['ahosts']))
```

And add this inside your form **or** give the button a name

```
<input type="hidden" name="ahosts" value="1" />
<!-- or -->
<button type="submit" name="ahosts" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you make a mistake here :

```
if(isset($_POST['ahosts']))
```

You check if `isset()` POST request but actually you send GET request ...

read the documentation https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

So if you change your code to:

```
 if(isset($_GET['ahosts']))
```

this will return true and now you will have a response

Comment: Guys many Thanks  ! -- Popnoodles thanks very much your suggestions have rsolved the issue for me -- Great ! :)

Comment: Hi Guys, just a  follow up question. I have a similar form to one above but this one uses a drop down menu to choose a "group" i've used the same logic with ajax as above, the page is working in the sense i get the results expected but the problem is the page is not refreshing, i added the new code above :

Comment: Hi, the main reason for using ajax is to prevent refreshing the page